# Returning response with header 'Content-Type' as 'application/ld+json'

Tags: flask, http-headers, mime-types, json-ld, eve

What would be the recommended way for overriding default (XML and/or JSON) HTML response header field 'Content-Type' to JSON-LD's "application/ld+json" upon GET calls to a python Eve API?

The intent here being:

1. Retrieve documents stored in a mongodb collection, with filters
   based on custom provided Eve schema,
2. Using event-hook "on_fetched_resource" attach the json-ld context 
   in "@context"
   dictionary field and list of documents under the "@graph" field
   before returning the response,
3. Also change HTML header 'Content-type' to JSON-LD's before returning
   the response.

From Eve docs the natively handled 'Content-type' seem fairly hardcoded.

I investigated the use of [mimerender](https://github.com/martinblech/mimerender), hinted from [flask-mimerenderer](https://github.com/nicolaiarocci/flask-mimerender), trying to **override via a decorator** the custom function added to app.on_fetched_resource - which processes the changes to the "response" dictionary (containing fields "_items" etc.) to make it JSON-LD - so as to try and **get the response to sport the "application/ld+json" tag**.

```
    from eve import Eve

    app = Eve(settings=mongo_settings)

    def before_returning_items(resource_name, response):

        # Process response dict to make contents json-ld compliant.
        # In particular add "@context" key/value pair, and
        # store documents retrieved in "_items" to "@graph" instead.

        return response


    app.on_fetched_resource += before_returning_items

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        app.run()
```

However I did not find exactly how to put the different pieces that are Flask, Eve, and mimerender together to obtain a ld+json tag to requests.get calls with header {'content-type': 'application/ld+json'}...

Best outcome I managed to obtain so far was by editing the Eve render.py for adding the entry:

```
    {'mime': ('application/ld+json',), 'renderer': 'render_json', 'tag': 'JSON-LD'}
```

to the _MIME_TYPES list.

However ideally I would obviously rather obtain the desired outcome of an additional response mimetype through changing settings or making use of an additional module such as mimerender than tweaking library/module code...

What might the recommended method be in this case?